# Limit the scope of variables storing error

Tags: go, error-handling, scope

I have the following code:

```
if entryJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(entry, "", " "); err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    log.Println(entryJson)
}

if err := ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

I want to limit the scope of *err* as much as possible. The problem I'm facing with this is, that the variable `entryJson` is out of scope when I want to write it to the file.
What is the idiomatic way to deal with this. Should I just reuse the variable *err* and check for it in an additional *if* block? Like this:

```
entryJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(entry, "", " ")
if err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    log.Println(entryJson)
}

err = ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644)
if err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
}
```

This works but looks less readable to me.

Comment: 1. why do you want to limit it? what's your logic there.
2.  both `if err = ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil{}` and `if err := ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil{}` works fine

Comment: I have no particular reason limiting the scope. It just seemed a good idea and was encouraged by the course I took. (I'm fairly new to Go coming from a Java background.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need to isolate variables.
Second, you can do short-hand assignment inside if statements, for example:

```
entryJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(entry, "", " ")
if err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
} else {
    log.Println(entryJson)
}

if err = ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
}

// or if you want to limit the scope of err badly, this is also legal:

if err := ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil{
    log.Println(err)
}
```

A clean way to handle this specific example though is to put it in it is own function and call it:

```
func writeJSON(fn string, v interface{}) error {
    j, err := json.MarshalIndent(v, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return ioutil.WriteFile(fn, j, 0644)
}

func main() {
    var test struct {
        A string
        B string
    }
    if err := writeJSON("file.json", test); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand of Go, which is admittedly not that much yet, I find the second solution of this answer to be the best. In my specific example this is particular true since I have now another methods which will use the same logic to write to the JSON. Therefore putting it into a separate function makes the most sense and limits the scope. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris welcome to Go, the #1 tip I can give you is, don't try to apply other languages to Go, once you can do that, your experience with Go will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can write file in the `else` statement following the error checking, although I can't say it's idiomatic/readable.

```
var entry = []byte(`{
    "name": "bob",
    "age" : 74
}`)

func main() {
    if entryJson, err := json.MarshalIndent(entry, "", " "); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        if err = ioutil.WriteFile("text.json", entryJson, 0644); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }   
    }
}
```